# How do custom model binders affect testing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I've had to create a custom model binder to bind data for a complex object, see here:
[Custom model binder for child collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086201/custom-model-binder-for-child-collection)

However, I'd like to know how doing this affects testing because if I test the controller method just straight up (not setting up a context etc) the binder should fail right? Maybe I'm just not clear on how to test a controller.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just test them independently.

The binder is required to properly form an instance of an object to pass to the Controller action when in the ASP.NET MVC pipeline, you do not need to test that it is invoked at the appropriate time. Just test that given the correct inputs, your custom binder produces the correct outputs and the same for your controller (and any negative tests you feel are appropriate).

Comment: I think @rich.okelly nailed it: test the independently.

The only think that I would add is there are several other issues to keep in mind when testing controllers. For example, when a controller is executed at runtime a bunch of events are fired (e.g. OnActionExecuting, OnActionExecuted) but these methods are not automatically executed when you test through your unit tests. This makes testing controllers harder to test since there is a lot of coupling.